# MySql randomize the last 10 rows

Tags: php, mysql, random

I need help on how to randomize the last 10 rows of MySql records.

```
$mysqld = mysql_query(select * from table where amount > amount2 and code = '$code' order by time DESC limit 1);
```

From the statement above I need to randomize the last 10 rows ordered by time but limited only 1 to display.

**EDIT**: In other words, I need to have the table ordered by time and then I need to focus on the last 10 rows. From these last 10 rows, I need to pick one and it must be random, which one I get.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: The last ten rows of what? You have a LIMIT 1 in your query, so it will only return one row.

Comment: if you only want to display 1 then why would you randomize the last 10?

Comment: He wants one random row but only picked from the last ten rows (chronologically). If you don't randomize the last ten rows then he'll get the same row every time which is not what he wants.

Comment: you mean `order by time DESC`?

Comment: i only want to display either the no 7 from the last, no 6, 9, but random. One random data from last 10 records is that possible?

Comment: "I need to randomize the last 10 rows, order by time [...]" - Not understood. You cannot both order them and randomize them at the same time.

Comment: you can get the last 10 rows using SELECT blabla query LIMIT 10, return it to your array, and then use shuffle function, and then just take any value out of the array.

Comment: @Steeven - yes he can, Piskvor has posted the correct solution (which admittedly uses a subquery, but it is sill possible)

Comment: Okay, understood. You should edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @kissmyface: Subqueries are not evil *per se*: the resulting temporary table will be tiny - only 10 rows in size, and thus will probably fit into memory.

Comment: @Piskvor - I know, but I was just making the point that this is not using *one* query strictly, but two (because it is executing a subquery). I'm not criticizing your solution - it's the best way to solve the probelm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that `time` is the time when record was inserted, this will get you the latest 10 rows from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `amount` > `amount2` AND `code` = '$code'
  ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Now, you can use the result as a temporary table, sort it randomly (as it's only 10 rows) and return one row:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `amount` > `amount2` AND `code` = '$code'
    ORDER BY `time` DESC LIMIT 10
) AS temptable 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try....

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM yerTable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) AS tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Obviously replace id with any other distinct column if preferred.

Comment: Which 1) does something quite different (gives 4 rows from anywhere in the table), and 2) is horribly inefficient (runs `RAND()` for every row in the table; say hello to Mr. Filesort ;))

Comment: I'm sure he'd be clever enough to add the 2nd limit

Comment: My above comment is no longer applicable to your revision of the answer.

Comment: @Brian - yeah but you have edited your answer since I posted my comment to make it correct, because it was totally wrong before.